# 1080p AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avcapturesession

I'm writing an app that reads a external video source as an AVCaptureInput. I plan on using a blackmagic device. When fetching for devices, I see the blackmagic device, however, it's preview is a black screen. I'm thinking it's because of the capture preset.

I need to get a AVCapture in 1080p but the highest preset available is 1280x720.  Is it possible? What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

### The options according to [AVCaptureSession class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureSession/sessionPreset)

```
NSString *const  AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto ;
NSString *const  AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh ;
NSString *const  AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium ;
NSString *const  AVCaptureSessionPresetLow ;
NSString *const  AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288 ;
NSString *const  AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 ;
NSString *const  AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720 ;
NSString *const  AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 ;
NSString *const  AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame960x540 ;
NSString *const  AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame1280x720 ;
NSString *const  AVCaptureSessionPresetInputPriority;
```

I think you'll find 1920x1080 to be the highest. What is actually available is dependent on the input device.

I believe you can check if an input supports the preset with:

```
- (BOOL)canSetSessionPreset:(NSString *)preset
```

or its Swift analogue.